# Can a SQL Default Value be calculated?

Tags: sql-server-2014, default-value, liquibase, calculated-columns, calculated-field

If I have the table `FOO` with the columns NUMBER - `FOO.ID`, VARCHAR - `FOO.LABEL` is there a way I can have SQL set a calculated `DEFAULT VALUE` for `FOO.LABEL` to be like *"DFLT_LBL_" + `FOO.ID`*

I.E a record with `ID` = 1 would have `LABEL` set to "DFLT_LBL_1" and a record with `ID` 2 would have `LABEL` set to "DFLT_LBL_2" and so on.

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: You can do it by using `before insert trigger`. Default value means that if you dont provide any value for that column while inserting, then the default value is inserted instead of null. So in your case, the values are not default. They should be derived based on `foo.id`, which could be done by trigger.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One method that works in all databases is to use a view:

```
create view v_table as 
    select t.*, concat(label, id) as label
    from foo t;
```

This would not allow you to change it.  You could have a column in the table called something like `override_label`, which has a `NULL` default and then the view is:

```
create view v_table as 
    select t.*, coalesce(override_label, concat(label, id)) as label
    from foo t;
```

In some databases, you can do something similar with a computed column:

```
alter table foo add label as (coalesce(override_label, concat(label, id)));
```

Comment: Yea the entire system already looks at this table directly, and it still has to have the ability to update to a custom value, its just that if it is inserted as null they want this default pattern.  I think a trigger would work best

Comment: @AdamJames . . . It is clearly your decision.  I find triggers to be hard to maintain, so I would prefer the last solution, because SQL Server supports computed columns.